# Removing row from a table if a matching element exists elsewhere

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

on my page I have a table list which displays a list of users that are linked to an organization:

```
<script type="text/html" id="userListTemplate">
    <div id="user_list_box">
        <table class="list" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
            {{#Users}}
            <tr id="user_row_{{UserId}}">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_user" data-userid="{{UserId}}" /></td>
                <td><span><a class="edit_user_link" data-userid="{{UserId}}" href="#">{{UserName}}</a></span></td>
            </tr>
            {{/Users}}
        </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

On the same page I also have a section which provides a list of users that can be associated with the organization:

```
<script type="text/html" id="linkedUserTemplate">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion_parent">
        {{#ChildOrganizations}}
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div id="collapse_{{OrganizationId}}" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <table class="list" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                        {{#Users}}
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_linked_user" data-userid="{{UserId}}" /></td>
                            <td>{{UserName}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {{/Users}}
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/ChildOrganizations}}
    </div>
</script>
```

This is all working fine when it comes to affiliating users with the organization. My issue, however, is that once a user has been selected from the second extract and added to the list in my first snippet, I would like to ensure that the same item is no longer rendered in the selectable list in the future. What would be the best way to go about this? I assume I should be looking at comparing the *data-userid* value in the list of linked users and the list of selectable users.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the action use the Distinct() and then pass it to view.

```
Model.Distinct().ToList();
```